# LocationServices.API is not available on this device

Tags: java, android, location

I'm calling a location service api from my android device, the application has my location access but when i run my app, I get the following error

```java
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: LocationServices.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.innoviti.sroconnect.MainActivity.lambda$getCurrentLocation$13$com-innoviti-sroconnect-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:648)
        at com.innoviti.sroconnect.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda11.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: LocationServices.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ApiExceptionMapper.getException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zag.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zai(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:58)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Android skd Version : 30
device : Plixel 3 XL (virtual)

what could be the cause and how do i resolve this?

Comment: It seems like an internet issue. To check that open Google Map installed in the emulator. If you dont see it working then it could be that. I would create a new emulator and try with that.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the Emulator controls (Three dots menu) and in the Location tab, pin any location in the map and click Set Location.

Then verify if you received the location you were expecting in your app.

Comment: it did not resolve my problem

Comment: do you check that google map of you emulator getting your location or not?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).